# OAuth2 OpenID Connect Third Party Initated Login with implicit flow

Tags: oauth2, openid-connect, openid

I'm working within a spec that uses the OpenID Connect third party initiated login + implicit flow. I first have to register my application with the third party, providing them a login initiation url, redirect uri, target link uri. Then the user flow is:

- The user is already logged into the third party application
- The user will click on a link to my application
- If authentication succeeds, the third party application will display my application's content in an iFrame

The authentication flow is as follows:

- User clicks on the link to my application
- Third party application POSTs to my login initiation url with client_id, login_hint
- My backend does an authentication request to the third party's /authorize_redirect endpoint (adding the state, nonce hash, redirect_uri etc. as query params)
- Third party application validates the authentication request
- If the authentication request is valid, the third party application POSTs id_token JWT and state value to my redirect_uri
- My backend validates the authentication response (id_token JWT signature, nonce, etc)
- If the authentication response is valid, I can navigate the user to a target link uri which would be displayed in an iFrame

My question is about after the whole flow is done and my content loads in the iFrame. Let's say I was displaying a frontend index.html, and maybe the frontend needs to fetch some data from my backend. Is there a standard secure way to authenticate the frontend with the backend based on the already-successful OIDC flow? When the index.html loads, the only way I can think of that it could be aware of anything having happened, is if there were a non-HttpOnly cookie, or some query param, but I'm not sure what would be safe to put there.

Comment: Welcome to the community. How do you secure your iframe from being copied as a link and just opened in a new tab? Because an iframe can just get opened in a new tab.

Comment: Thank you @SirMuffington! It's not secured so it could be opened in a new tab, but requests to the backend wouldn't work because the user making the requests would either need to log in or go through another OAuth2 flow to generate an access token. That's the part I'd like to avoid, though I'm open to anything, because the user is already logged into the third party system and is launching out to my application with the OIDC 3rd-party initated flow.

Comment: Hmm, I think relying on iframes in this scenario equals not using state-of-the-art tech. And I personally think iframes are not meant for this use case actually.

Comment: It seems that your application does not store in any way the fact that the user was successfully authenticated.